# trouble setting up a mail server in cent os

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

I've been following this tutorial : [http://www.linuxmail.info/](http://www.linuxmail.info/mail-server-setup-centos-6/)  to set a mail server on centOS 6.  Everything was going fine until I reached this section : [http://www.linuxmail.info/](http://www.linuxmail.info/postfix-smtp-auth-dovecot-sasl-centos-6/) .  When I try and connect to my domain name via SMTP I get a connection refused but I've I use pop3 I connect to dovecot fine.

Comment: Check your logs and give us the error recorded, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more official-ish docs on the CentOS wiki:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_sasl

Probably a few others.

There could be a number of things that are wrong.  One in particular is your ISP blocking port 25 traffic as an anti-spam measure.  In that case, you should be using the SMTP submission port (587) for Postfix, or SMTPS (SSL-enabled SMTP) on port 465.

Verify that Postfix is listening to the public interface, e.g., `netstat -pant |grep ":25"`.

If it's a SASL authentication issue, check your logs.

*update*

From the netstat output in the comments, it looks like Postfix is only listening to localhost.

Look at [CentOS Wiki's Postfix configuration guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix#head-d7bc8b1398b0a0cf6f9ef2556e4db84812c8dbfd) for the available options.  In particular, you want to set `inet_interfaces = all` from whatever the default is in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and reload.

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15363/master

Comment: Ah, it's only listening on localhost.  In that case, you should have an entry in `main.cf` like `inet_interfaces`.  Set it so that you have `inet_interfaces = all`.  Check http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix#head-d7bc8b1398b0a0cf6f9ef2556e4db84812c8dbfd for more details.

Comment: lol, I uncommented it and left the localhost one uncommented aswell. Can connect to it fine now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

doublecheck `mynetworks` you should include here your local network with netmask or the server probably will relay only emails from localhost

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    reject_unauth_destination
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

Comment: Yeah, they're all there.

Comment: what about your firewall? Does it allow traffic from external?